# How to lock a python main method invoked from two diffrent terminals

Tags: python, multithreading, locking, python-multiprocessing

Suppose I have a main method which read/writes data into a file. Now If I invoke the python file from two different terminals (two different processes ?) How Can I make sure that only one process can use that method ?

I used `threading.Lock()` but that is not working because I guess the lock object is not visible to another process opened in another terminal. Am I right ?

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: @ Peter Wood debian linux

Answer (score 1):

https://pythonhosted.org/lockfile/lockfile.html

```
from lockfile import LockFile
lock = LockFile("/some/file/or/other")
with lock:
    print lock.path, 'is locked.'
```

Using flock:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/fcntl.html#fcntl.flock

Docs for flock:
http://linux.die.net/man/2/flock